# how do i get my sidebar above content on nanomag theme

Tags: sidebar

my site when it loads in a responsive mode the sidebar is below almost everything else is there any way I can move it up a bit, any css i can put the theme is nanomag

Answer (score 0):

You could use some absolute positioning CSS for that media query for that class that displays the sidebar. It all depends on how the theme code is written, as does the actual name of the class that the theme uses. One tutorial on that subject is here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

You might be able to put your CSS in the Custom CSS of the Theme Customization, making sure you add the proper media query statement so it doesn't affect other screen resolutions. Otherwise, you'll have to do a Child Theme, so you don't mess with the theme's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the themes, sidebar are shown at bottom on responsive rather than top of content. You can move that by using media query statement on css section. Use proper position and styles at the required responsive one. You can add your custom css on Dashboard > Appearance > Customize and find Additional CSS. 
I found this article on google where you can get some hints. 
https://techtabby.com/move-sidebar-content-website-wordpress-genesis/